# Why can't R report the name for a corresponding max value?

Tags: r

I am using Illumina probes for gene expression. Here is an example data.frame (dat)

```
Probe_Id        IQR                 ILMN_Gene
ILMN_1672935    0.166315562147241   HSFY2
ILMN_1688833    0.17264685464698    HSFY2
ILMN_2291534    0.18944190618866    HSFY2
ILMN_2291538    0.186333177903791   HSFY2
ILMN_2401946    0.172348879737861   HSFY2
```

There is several more groups like this. I would like for each group (defined by ILMN_Gene) to get the probe with the highest IQR (Interquantile range) and report it as:

```
ILMN_2291534    0.18944190618866    HSFY2
```

My code:

```
final <- summarize(dat, maxIQR = max(IQR), probe = Probe_Id)
```

I get:

```
ILMN_1672935    0.18944190618866    HSFY2
```

Basically, the `probe_ID` is wrong. How could I specify that I want the probe ID with the max IQR?

Thank you!

Comment: I wonder what package `summarize()` is from?

Comment: You might get better interest if you properly titled your question "How can I return the names for max values.." rather than foolishly suggesting it can't be done in `R`

Comment: @MartinMorgan yeah: Hmisc, rockchalk, ABCExtremes,beadarray... I quit looking :-)

Comment: I think it's the one all the kids are raving about, `dplyr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ILMN_Gene) %>% filter(IQR==max(IQR))
#       Probe_Id       IQR ILMN_Gene
# 1 ILMN_2291534 0.1894419     HSFY2
```

data

```
df <- structure(list(Probe_Id = structure(1:5, .Label = c("ILMN_1672935", 
"ILMN_1688833", "ILMN_2291534", "ILMN_2291538", "ILMN_2401946"
), class = "factor"), IQR = c(0.166315562147241, 0.17264685464698, 
0.18944190618866, 0.186333177903791, 0.172348879737861), ILMN_Gene = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "HSFY2", class = "factor")), .Names = c("Probe_Id", 
"IQR", "ILMN_Gene"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x02fd24a0>)
```

Answer (score 3):

Or using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)

dt[,.SD[which.max(IQR)], by = ILMN_Gene]
   ILMN_Gene     Probe_Id       IQR
1:     HSFY2 ILMN_2291534 0.1894419
```